# What is the difference between Azure Function App and Web App

Tags: azure, function, azure-web-app-service, cloud, azure-function-app

at the moment i'am working on my Study-Project for my Bachelor-degree. i'am implementing a VM-Cost-Optimization in python, which sends automated E-Mails. For that Use-Case I picked an Azure Function App.
I have to document my work and my decision for the Azure Function App (for example instead of a web app).
Microsoft don't really offers a documentation for the difference or for the Azure Function App at all.
What is the difference between a Function App and Web App ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I saw this Thread already before posting my question. It don't really answers my question because there is nothing about Function Apps.

Comment: There is an explanation for Azure Functions. Azure Function App and Azure Function are the same.

Comment: Okay that explains a lot. Thank you !